# Edit standalone XAML with Visual Studio Intellisense

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I am using XAML for designing interactive layouts that are not part of a program or Visual Studio project. They are loaded at runtime.

If I open a single XAML file in Visual Studio 2013 it is treated as regular XML with no intellisense for XAML/WPF controls :-(. In VS2010 this worked out of the box.

Is there a way to profit from VS2013 XAML intellisense without including a XAML file in a project?
All questions/answers I found on Intellisense are in the context of a regular Visual Studio project.

Comment: Is this really not possible with VS2013?!?! This is really a step back from VS2010... :-(

Comment: So this does not seem to be possible?!??
I am confused. On one hand MS turns to XAML in more and more areas on the other hand they limit the support for XAML as general purpose design language/format... 
Too bad as technically XAML would do an excellent job on this.

Answer (score 1):

What about Expression Blend ? 
The old versions of Expression Blend lets you design in XAML with Intellisense.

Perhaps Blend for VS2013?

Comment: I have tried that, but unfortunately blend says that it "can not find Blend project files" in the same directory as the XAML file. 
The Blend File menu does not have an option for opening XAML. If you force it to open XAML via "Open With" in file explorer you get the message above.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it is unfortunate that you cannot edit a stand alone xaml in blend. 
I create a bogus WPF project in blend, then - add existing item - find my xaml  - add as link.

Once my standalone xaml is part of the WPF project the xaml editor works the way I want and need.